# Is there an app, or method, to read .desktop file with url links via a file manager

Tags: url

At the moment I can move the .desktop file to the android device and (using FX File Explorer) open as application, choose Firefox, allow Firefox to access files and then it works. But whilst giving a file manager access to my files is a necessity, I don't really want Firefox to have access to my files (which it presumably needs by this method in order to 'read' the .desktop file). I really want the file explorer app to 'read' the .desktop file (as it already has access rights) and then forward the url it found there to my browser.

This is exactly the way both my cloud storage apps (Dropbox and Nextcloud) work when they encounter .desktop files. They just open the url in a browser without needing the browser itself to access the file.

Is there a way to make this happen within a file explorer app?

Comment: Are you talking about the `.desktop` files used by Linux desktop environments like [this](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)? It's just a text file that can be opened in any text editor. Or is it some other `.desktop` file?

Comment: Yes, the Linux created ones. Specifically just those used to store Url weblinks

Comment: You can use a file explorer like MiXplorer which has a text editor built-in. It's free and ad-free. Or you can go for some other similar file explorer.

Comment: As per the question. File explorers simply open the text document with a browser which then needs file access permissions (which I don't want to grant) to 'read' the URL. I was looking for an app which did the 'reading' and just opened a browser at the specified URL.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get your point. Do you want to open the `.desktop` file which contains a URL or you want to open the URL itself? Can you please share a sample of such `.desktop` file e.g. on https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: @Isaacson If FX File Explorer is your preferred file manager app why not writing to the author and ask for .desktop file support?

Comment: @Robert Looks like that might be my best bet, thanks.